# c# List<T> group by year then by month

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a List how can I group the items per year and then by month?

Of course for year would be something like:

```
list.GroupBy(t=>t.Created.Year);
```

Comment: Can you give an example on how you are expecting the end result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 list.GroupBy(t => new { Year = t.Created.Year, Month = t.Created.Month });
```